# Click doesn't get prop data attribute of "this" on first click

Tags: jquery

I have a simple html link, which when I click it, I want to read a `data` attribute and change attributes on the link and also the link text.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="heightSystem" data-heightSystem="imperial">change to metres &amp; cm</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
var cb = {};

cb.domChange = {
    heightSystem: function(){
        if($(this).prop('data-heightSystem') == 'metric'){
            $(this)
                .prop('data-heightSystem', 'imperial')
                .html('change to feet &amp; inches');
        } else {
            $(this)
                .prop('data-heightSystem', 'metric')
                .html('change to metres &amp; cm');
        }
    }
}

// click handler
$('.heightSystem').click(cb.domChange.heightSystem);
```

**The problem**

The changes only take place after the first click - from the second click onwards, everything works as it should - why is this?

When I `console.log($(this).prop('data-heightSystem'))` I get `undefined` on the first click

**Also tried but didn't work at all for some reason??**

```
if($(this).data('heightSystem') == 'metric'){ ... }
```

[Here's a fiddle showing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/qfq255tg/)

Comment: Also note that `.data()` returns `jquery`, not the `value` of `data attr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ***set*** a data-attribute, you'd use `attr()` and not `prop()`.
Also, you have the HTML part mixed up

```js
var cb = {};

cb.domChange = {
    heightSystem: function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-heightSystem') == 'metric') {
            $(this).attr('data-heightSystem', 'imperial')
                   .html('change to metres &amp; cm');
                
        } else {
            $(this).attr('data-heightSystem', 'metric')
                   .html('change to feet &amp; inches');
        }
    }
}

$('.heightSystem').click(cb.domChange.heightSystem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="heightSystem" data-height-system="imperial">change to metres &amp; cm</a>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I just tried to delete the question as I realised my error but your answer got there - thanks - my logic fail!

Answer (score 0):

I updated the logic to match the correct wording...

This is using the 'data' attribute

```js
var cb = {};

cb.domChange = {
  heightSystem: function() {
    var elem = $('.heightSystem');
    var elemData = $(elem).data('heightsystem');

    if (elemData === 'imperial') {
      $(elem).data('heightsystem', 'metric');
      $(elem).html('change to feet &amp; inches');

    } else {
      $(elem).data('heightsystem', 'imperial');
      $(elem).html('change to metres &amp; cm');

    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('a.heightSystem').on('click', cb.domChange.heightSystem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="heightSystem" data-heightSystem="imperial">change to metres &amp; cm</a>
```